# EPICOR ERP API DOCUMENTATION

Tags: epicorerp, epicor

I am entirely new  to Epicor ERP.
I want to design a system with Epicor as the backend and react js as the frontend. The problem is that I can't find the Epicor API Documentation anywhere. From where do I get the API documentation? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation by navigating to your Epicor server like this

```
https://[your epicor server]/EpicorERP/api/help/v2/
```

There you will find all of the different categories of APIs available,
such as Business Objects, Reports, Libraries, Procedures, Etc.
Here is one service exposed by the Business Object

```
https://[your epicor server]/EpicorERP/api/help/v2/odata/Erp.BO.SalesOrderSvc/index
```

This is a swagger page that goes very well into detail on how to interact with the API